# Is it possible to allow all users in a specific AAD tenant to access an app?

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is it possible to allow all users in a specific AAD tenant to access an app?

Something like a tenant trust. Tenant 1 trusts Tenant 2 and I can add 'tenant2\AllUsers' to a permission.

I want to allow all users of a partner tenant (current and future) to be able to access a SharePoint site and a few other apps.

I've looked at B2B but it requires invitations which is hard to manage at scale.
Entitlement management looks nice but requires P2 licenses and has lots of capabilities we just don't need.
Does anyone have a simple way to do a 'tenant trust'? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have a misunderstanding of "tenant trust".

When we say tenant trust, it means the tenant trusts an app and then the app can access the data of that tenant. There is not a way to make a tenant trust another tenant.

Anyway, using the official admin consent URL you can grant admin consent for a whole tenant to an app.

See [Construct the URL for granting tenant-wide admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent).

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id of partner tenant}/adminconsent?client_id={client-id}
```

Sign in with an admin account from partner tenant and do the admin consent. Then all users from partner tenant can sign in to this app.

For SharePoint user case, you can take advantage of self-enroll service. Please refer to [Use SharePoint as a business-to-business (B2B) extranet solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/create-b2b-extranet) and [Create a B2B extranet with managed guests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/solutions/b2b-extranet?view=o365-worldwide).